# In bash how do you delete a partial word similar to ctrl-w

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

Say I have a directory with one file in it
mylongfilename.blahdeblah.txt
now the keystrokes
mv [tab] [tab]
will result in
mv mylongfilename.blahdeblah.txt mylongfilename.blahdeblah.txt
on my command line

What I'd now like to do is type something in the place of the second blahdeblah
If I hit ctrl-b a few times I'll be back at the . before .txt
At this point I want to type something like ctrl-w to delete to the preceding .
Ie I'd end up with
mv mylongfilename.blahdeblah.txt mylongfilename..txt

Is there a keystroke similar to ctrl-w that will do that?
(Ctrl-w will delete to the preceding space - not what I want)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be in emacs mode. To do what you want there, this works:

```
meta-backspace
```

(Strictly speaking it's M-Del. See [this page](http://www.math.uh.edu/~bgb/emacs_keys.html) for more Emacs keybindings. I don't think Bash's emacs mode supports them all, but it supports this one.)

```
telemachus ~ $ mv mylongfilename.blahblah.txt mylongfilename.|.txt
```

The pipe shows were the cursor ends up.

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I wanted. stackoverflow/serverfault shows it's awesomeness yet again.

Comment: Various Emacs bindings do work in bash (terminator, gnome-terminal or xterm in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS), but `M-Del` doesn't (it returns `~3`). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Bash has emacs and vi modes. In vi mode, simply dw for delete word, or cw for change word. set -o vi to get into vi mode. There's probably an emacs mode equivalent.

man readline is the reference for bash keyboard stuff, and bash specific editions to readline are in man bash.

Comment: I'm a Vim user, but I still find vi mode for Bash a bit painful. Maybe it's just that vi-mode isn't quite Vim. Still, b, b, db, i seems to do what the OP wants here. (For some reason 2b produces odd results for me. It should move me back two word boundaries - onto the first '.', no?) In this case emacs mode seems to win.

Answer (score 1):

From man bash:

```
COMP_WORDBREAKS
    The set of characters that the Readline library treats as word separators when
    performing  word  completion.   If COMP_WORDBREAKS is unset, it loses its special
    properties, even if it is subsequently reset.
```

Changing this should change the characters used as word breaks, so if you added '.' to it's current value, then Ctrl-w would delete back to the '.' instead of back to the preceeding space.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work, should have tried it before posting.  Telemachus is right when he says meta-backspace or M-Del.

Comment: Funny, since I was just about to try your idea. It sounds like it _should_ work.

Comment: Yeah, it's for word/command completion.  The COMP_ prefix should have been a giveaway.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to swap the words to put the part `blahdeblah` at the end of the line (with Esc-T) and then remove the end of the line:

- mv [tab] [tab]

  mv mylongfilename.blahdeblah.txt mylongfilename.blahdeblah.txt
- [Esc-T] (Swap the last two words before the cursor)

  mv mylongfilename.blahdeblah.txt mylongfilename.txt .blahdeblah
- [Ctrl-w]

  mv mylongfilename.blahdeblah.txt mylongfilename.txt

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted but handy to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that you have quite a few such 'mv' operations to do in that directory, why not write a short translation script using say, 'sed'?

You'll find some tricks [here](http://daemonforums.org/showthread.php?p=19829). But don't let that limit you, but all means lookup some more sed and awk too.

Comment: Yeah - I've been doing some sed for other things. But I'm looking for a simple solution for once-off things. Or rather, not once-off but where scripting is overkill. rather than pressing backspace 8 times. It'd just be handy to have a keystroke like ctrl-w.

Comment: Ok, have it your way. But, i have seen many times that trying to get a 'simple' solution ends up with a lot of time lost.

Comment: Or you could see that this question will apply to far more situations in future than the one at hand, and is thus worth answering directly!